# Unable to insert rows in Datagrid using DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

The records from my `ObservableCollection` are correctly loaded in my `datagrid`, I'm able to edit the existing rows but I can't insert new rows.

I'm using a `DataGridTemplateColumn` in my `View` as follows:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ListRoundViewModel}" CanUserAddRows="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Number">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Number, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Number, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Here is my `ViewModel`:

```
public class SettingsViewModel 
{       

    public ObservableCollection<Round> ListRoundViewModel { get; set; }

    public SettingsViewModel()
    {

        ListRoundViewModel = new ObservableCollection<Round>();
        ListRoundViewModel.Add(new Round(10));
        ListRoundViewModel.Add(new Round(5));
        ListRoundViewModel.Add(new Round(8));

    }
}
```

I simply set the `DataContext` when the view is loaded :

```
private void Settings_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataContext = new SettingsViewModel();
}
```

And the `Model` for the object type used in the `ObservableCollection`

```
public class Round : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int_number;


    public Round()
    {

    }

    public Round(int number)
    {
        this._number = number;
    }


    public int Number
    {
        get
        {
            return _number;
        }
        set
        {
            _number = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Number");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    } 
}
```

On another hand, using a `DataGridTextColumn` such as behind, inserting a row works perfectly.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Binding="{Binding Path=Number, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

When running the App, it seems that the Datagrid's BeginEdit event is not fired on the last row.

I don't know if I correctly exposed my problem but the `DataGridTextColum` class don't fit my UI needs and the `DataGridTemplateColumn` does.

Comment: Does adding ```TwoWay``` binding to your ```ItemsSource``` work? ```ItemsSource="{Binding ListRoundViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}"```

Comment: No, it doesn't work

Comment: If i just keep the `CellEditingTemplate`, i'm able to add new rows and the source is correctly updated