# Can't create new rows manually in DataGrid with columns of DataGridTemplateColumn type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

## Summary

In my application I have a WPF DataGrid with several DataGridTemplateColumns. For some reason the user cannot manually add rows in the DataGrid by hitting the Enter-key. I have other DataGrids where there are only DataGridTextcolumns. In this DataGrid the user can add new rows by hitting the Enter-key.

## Description

I can reproduce the problem with a small application with three DataGrids.

The first DataGrid contains only of a DataGridTextColumn. If I click the initial row in the column I can type something in the column and hit enter. This will automatically create a new row and my ObservableCollection is automatically updated containing 1 element for the row I just created.
So this seems to work as expected.

The second DataGrid only contains of a DataGridTemplateColumn, with a Slider. But with this DataGrid I cannot add a new row as the first.
I just want to set the value of the slider and press the Enter-key. Then I want a new row with another slider in the DataGrid.

In my third DataGrid I have combined the two grids with a DataGridTextColumn and a DataGridTemplateColumn with the same setup. In this DataGrid I can only add a new row if I click the Enter-key in the DataGridTextColumn.

## Code

Bellow is the reproduceable code. Just create a new WPF applicaiton called WpfApp1 in VS and copy paste in the MainWindow.xaml and MainWindow.xaml.cs.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

        <Label Content="Can create a new row manually in the grid by hitting enter in the 'Text' column" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Models1}" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Text" Width="300" />

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <Button Content="Summary" Height="40" Click="Button_Click" Margin="0,20,0,20" />

        <Label Content="Can't create a new row manually in the grid by hitting enter" />
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Models2}" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Number" Width="300">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <Slider Value="{Binding Number, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Minimum="1" Maximum="300" />

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <Label Content="Can create a new row manually in the grid by hitting enter in the 'Text' column" Margin="0,80,0,0" />
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Models3}" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Text" Width="100" />

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Number" Width="300">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <Slider Value="{Binding Number, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Minimum="1" Maximum="300" />

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>



            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

using System.Windows;


namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var vm = DataContext as ViewModel;
            var t1 = $"All text: {string.Join(", ", vm.Models1.Select(r => r.Text))}";
            var t2 = $"All numbers: {string.Join(", ", vm.Models2.Select(r => r.Number))}";
            var t3 = $"All numbers: {string.Join(", ", vm.Models3.Select(r => r.Number))}";
            MessageBox.Show($"Summary: {Environment.NewLine} {t1} {Environment.NewLine} {t2} {Environment.NewLine} {t3}");
        }
    }

    class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string text;
        double number;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Model()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set
            {
                if (value != text)
                {
                    text = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Text)));
                }
            }
        }

        public double Number
        {
            get { return number; }
            set
            {
                if (value != number)
                {
                    number = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Number)));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Model> Models1 { get; private set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Model> Models2 { get; private set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Model> Models3 { get; private set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Models1 = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
            Models2 = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
            Models3 = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        }

    }
}
```

## Other

I suspect the DataGridTemploateColumn has another behaviour then the DataGridTextColumn. That would be good to know in the future. But the problem still exist.

The problem is simple: How to a manually add a new row in the DataGrid where there are one or several DataGridTemplateColumns?

I found this post ([Unable to insert rows in Datagrid using DataGridTemplateColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52930913/unable-to-insert-rows-in-datagrid-using-datagridtemplatecolumn)) with more or less the same problem.
The recommendation was to change the DataGridTemplateColumn's CellTemplate to CellEditingTemplate. But this didn't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: You tried CellEditingTemplate? It seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You could call `BeginEdit()` to insert a new row, for example by handling the `KeyDown` of the `Slider`:

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        dg.BeginEdit();
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Slider Value="{Binding Number, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Minimum="1" Maximum="300"
        KeyDown="OnKeyDown"/>
```

You may also wrap this functionality in a custom `DataGridTemplateColumn` class:

```
public class CustomTemplateColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
{
    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        FrameworkElement fe = base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
        if (fe != null)
            fe.KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
        return fe;
    }

    private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridOwner.BeginEdit();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<local:CustomTemplateColumn Header="Number" Width="300">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <Slider Value="{Binding Number, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Minimum="1" Maximum="300" />

        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</local:CustomTemplateColumn>
```